# Configure S4 Device with Eclipse

Tags: android

I have an app and want to run it on S4 device not on emulator. But there is no option for USB debbug mode "on/off" i have seen . And on running eclipse is not showing the S4 device. Any help

Comment: Does `adb devices` show your device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be in Developer Options. If your device is running Android 4.2, Developer Options is hidden by default. To enable it:

• Go into Settings > About

• Tap on the Build Number entry seven times (Toasts will appear to help you keep count)

• Press BACK, and Developer Options should be in the Settings list

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html):

1. Declare your application as "debuggable" in your Android Manifest.
   When using Eclipse, you can skip this step, because running your app directly from the Eclipse IDE automatically enables debugging.
   In the AndroidManifest.xml file, add android:debuggable="true" to the  element.
   Note: If you manually enable debugging in the manifest file, be sure to disable it before you build for release (your published application should usually not be debuggable).
   **2. Enable USB debugging on your device.
   On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.
   On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.
   Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.**
2. Set up your system to detect your device.
   If you're developing on Windows, you need to install a USB driver for adb. For an installation guide and links to OEM drivers, see the OEM USB Drivers document.
   If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works. Skip this step.
   If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a udev rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the ATTR{idVendor} property. For a list of vendor IDs, see USB Vendor IDs, below. To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux:
   Log in as root and create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.
   Use this format to add each vendor to the file:
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC. The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node.
Note: The rule syntax may vary slightly depending on your environment. Consult the udev documentation for your system as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, see this guide to writing udev rules.